# How can I Pipe the output of FFMPEG 2 Levels of Piping in a bash script

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, grep, sed, pipe

I have been trying to pipe 2 levels deep.

I can pipe successfully:

1. ffmpeg | grep
2. ffmpeg | sed

I can not pipe

1. ffmpeg | grep | sed
2. ffmpeg | sed | grep

I don't understand, does ffmpeg limit to only one pipe in the chain?

**This code has NO OUTPUT with 2 pipes and no errors:**

```
ffmpeg -i "https://17563.live.streamtheworld.com/WETAFM.mp3?nocache=Ag6q8pw2" -af silencedetect=n=-10dB:d=0.5 -f null - 2>&1 | grep silence_duration | sed "s/.*silence_duration: \(.*\).*/\1/"
```

Expected Output:

```
2.06442
0.719252
0.594036
0.562698
0.500295
```

**This code has the correct output with 1 pipe:**

```
ffmpeg -i "https://17563.live.streamtheworld.com/WETAFM.mp3?nocache=Ag6q8pw2" -af silencedetect=n=-10dB:d=0.5 -f null - 2>&1 | grep silence_duration
```

Output:

```
[silencedetect @ 0000018027f9bd00] silence_end: 2.06442 | silence_duration: 2.06442
[silencedetect @ 0000018027f9bd00] silence_end: 3.45971 | silence_duration: 0.719252
[silencedetect @ 0000018027f9bd00] silence_end: 7.04399 | silence_duration: 0.594036
[silencedetect @ 0000018027f9bd00] silence_end: 7.81501 | silence_duration: 0.562698
[silencedetect @ 0000018027f9bd00] silence_end: 9.05535 | silence_duration: 0.500295
```

**This code has the correct output with 1 pipe:**

```
ffmpeg -i "https://17563.live.streamtheworld.com/WETAFM.mp3?nocache=Ag6q8pw2" -af silencedetect=n=-10dB:d=0.5 -f null - 2>&1 | sed "s/.*silence_duration: \(.*\).*/\1/"
```

Output:

```
[silencedetect @ 000001a48277b980] silence_start: 0
2.06442
[silencedetect @ 000001a48277b980] silence_start: 2.74045
0.719252
[silencedetect @ 000001a48277b980] silence_start: 6.44995
0.594036
[silencedetect @ 000001a48277b980] silence_start: 7.25231
0.562698
[silencedetect @ 000001a48277b980] silence_start: 8.55506
0.500295
```

Answer (score 3):

## Why is `grep | sed` not doing anything?

It is, but you didn't wait for it. If you press <kbd>q</kbd> then ffmpeg will close the stream the `silence_duration` values will be displayed.

If you want it to print the values immediately one method is to use `awk` instead.

## How to isolate the `silence_duration` values?

If the ultimate goal is to isolate the `silence_duration` values use `awk`:

```
ffmpeg -i "https://17563.live.streamtheworld.com/WETAFM.mp3?nocache=Ag6q8pw2" -af silencedetect=n=-10dB:d=0.5 -f null - 2>&1 |  awk -F ': ' '/silence_duration/ {print $3}'
```

Result:

```
2.06442
0.719252
0.594036
0.562698
0.663968
1.24109
```

However, I prefer to use the [(a)metadata](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#metadata_002c-ametadata) filter with filters that support metadata keys. It is more complicated, but the output is cleaner and easier to parse. You can easily either pipe the info (`file=-`) or output directly to a file (`file=silence.log`):

```
ffmpeg -loglevel error -i "https://17563.live.streamtheworld.com/WETAFM.mp3?nocache=Ag6q8pw2" -af silencedetect=n=-10dB:d=0.5,ametadata=mode=print:key=lavfi.silence_duration:file=- -f null - | awk -F = '/silence_duration/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This has been a great help for me, I took your code and modified it to append to a silence.log file with a slight variation: ffmpeg -loglevel error -i "https://17563.live.streamtheworld.com/WETAFM.mp3?nocache=Ag6q8pw2" -af silencedetect=n=-10dB:d=0.5,ametadata=mode=print:key=lavfi.silence_duration:file=- -t 30 -f null - | awk -F = '/silence_duration/ {print $2 >> "silence.log"}'

Comment: @JimDandyBOA Consider removing the `-t 30` if you want to process more than 30 seconds. I forgot to remove that from the answer originally.

Comment: Coincidentally, before you added the -t 30 I had added the exact same thing the night before to force writing to an output file because awk is buffering the output to file but does not buffer to the terminal screen.  My intentions were to call FFmpeg in a while loop as a hack.  This method worked but opened up a can of worms with repeated opening and closing.  Well, I learned a lot and hope that this post is useful to others.  Thanks again